# .ajax error - a is undefined a))();else c.error("Invalid JSON:

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

in the following code, why does it work:

```
var addresses = {"2-avenue-bir-hakiem": "2 Avenue Bir Hakiem", "56-rue-marcel-pagnol": "56 rue Marcel Pagnol"};
```

but

```
var addresses = json.val;
```

does not work

my json output is valid!

> {"2-avenue-bir-hakiem": "2 Avenue Bir
>   Hakiem", "56-rue-marcel-pagnol": "56
>   rue Marcel Pagnol"}

the error i get is

> a is undefined [Break on this error]
>   a))();else c.error("Invalid JSON:
>   "+a)...f(d)if(i)for(f in
>   a){if(b.apply(a[f],

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
    }

    $( "#companies" ).autocomplete({
        source: ";companies",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            $("#address").html(ui.item.id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: ';addresses?company=' + ui.item.id,
                dataType: 'json',
                // process the addresses
                success: function(json) {
                    $('body').append('Response Value: ' + json.val);
                    var opts = '';
                    var addresses = {"2-avenue-bir-hakiem": "2 Avenue Bir Hakiem", "56-rue-marcel-pagnol": "56 rue Marcel Pagnol"};
                    //var addresses = json.val;
                    $.each(addresses, function(k, v) {
                        opts += '<option>' + v + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#address').html(opts);
                }
            }); //end ajax
        } // end select
    });
});
</script>
```

what am i missing?

thanks

Comment: what does json, the var, look like? maybe you don't need the .val part?

Comment: I don't think you're actually getting an "Invalid JSON" error. You're using the minified jQuery which compresses a lot of stuff onto the same line. Use the unminified version (jquery.js rather than jquery.min.js) and see where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Try this before `$.each`, cause Jquery thinks that your answer is a string, not a JSON-object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not getting valid JSON back **from the server**, not that the `addresses` JSON is invalid (though it's just an object literal).  Are you sure this is the right URL?

```
url: ';addresses?company=' + ui.item.id
```

Check the response coming back in firebug, chrome, fiddler...whatever you can use to see *that* response, and check that it's valid here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

It appears from your symptoms that you're currently getting a completely empty response back, and I think the URL you're using is to blame, double check what you're trying to fetch.